# SQL Server stored procedure passing parameters into variables

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, dynamic, sql-server-2012

I have a big query which works and I want to write a stored procedure for it.
I'm getting this error:

> the OLE DB provider SQLNCLI11" for linked server "theServer" does not contain the table ""@dbName"."dbo"."tableName"

What I am trying to do:

```
create PROCEDURE [sys.sp_myProcedure] 
(
 @dbName varchar(30) output, 
 @rid varchar (10) output,
 @mdate output
 )
AS
BEGIN
declare @prt varchar(12)
declare @pid int
declare @cid int
--declare @rid int
declare @aid int

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
set @cid= (select CID from  theServer.[@dbName].dbo.tableName where RID= @rid)
set @pid= (select PID from  theServer.[@dbName].dbo.tableName where RID= @rid)
set @aid= (select aid from  theServer.[@dbName].dbo.tableName where RID= @rid)
--then my query begins
```

`theServer.[@dbName].dbo.tablename` is a linked server.

What I want to do is:

```
execute [sys.sp_myProcedure] 'someDbname', '123', '2012-03-03'
```

and the parameters passed here would set/update the variables `@dbName, @rid, @mdate`  at runtime. ( @mdate I have it further away in the query, it's too big to adapt it with myTable and to change all the sensitive data).

How can I do this ?? (using SQL Server 2012)

**edit (based on the comments and answers):**

so, it's `@thatString = '--insert the query here '` . Then, in my case how can i set those variables according to the parameters inside the query? Should i do it with replace? like this: `set @thatString= replace(@thatString, dbName, @dbname)` ?

**

### edit 2

**

```
set @sql = '
use [someDbName];
use [123];
use [2012-03-03];

select ... '
set @sql = replace (@sql, 'someDbName', @dbName)
set @sql = replace (@sql, '123', @rid)
set @sql = replace (@sql, '2012-03-03', @mdate)
execute @sql
end
```

Did i get it right? is the `execute @sql` in the right place?

I'm asking cause it doesnt work. i'm getting the name `' --part of my query here' is not a valid identifier`

Comment: You can't parameterize *names* in T-SQL. You'll have to construct the whole thing as a large string and pass it to `EXEC` (a.k.a. dynamic SQL)

Comment: I see, please see my edit and tell me if I got the idea

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: oh, didnt know that. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Names of databases or other objects cannot be specified dynamically from variables. The workaround is to compose a dynamic SQL query in a string, into which you concatenate the required names, and then `execute (@thatString)`.

(You might think you can employ `use`, but it is scoped such that you would have to include the rest of your query within the same executed string.)

--

Edit with more info as requested. You can compose the string however you like. If you need any more guidance, there are plenty of pages that discuss dynamic T-SQL. But hey, two ideas:

```
set @myDynamicQuery =
'
    use [' + @myDynamicDatabase + '];

    select BLAH from WHOM where DATA = ''what'';
';
```

or if you will be using the name a lot, you could reduce the hassle caused by breaking in and out of single quotes as follows - though I personally never use this as I don't like how it looks:

```
set @myDynamicQuery =
'
    use [A_RARE_PLACEHOLDER];

    select BLAH from WHOM where DATA = ''what'';

    -- lots more uses of A_RARE_PLACEHOLDER
';

set @myDynamicQuery = replace(
    @myDynamicQuery,
    'A_RARE_PLACEHOLDER',
    @myDynamicDatabase
);
```

Then `execute (@myDynamicQuery);`

Comment: thanks for this, but i'm new to this. Just to make sure: am i declaring @myDynamicDatabase in the stored procedure declaration? Also can i use this 3 times (cause i have 3 parameters?) like this: `use [' + @dbName + '];`
then `use [' + @rid+ '];` 'use [' + @mDate+ '];`

Comment: Have you actually tried any of this? If so, please follow the IT standard: What have you tried? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? Also, it's odd that you removed your accept vote, since I did answer the question you originally asked. If - after actually trying the code - you have different questions, they should be asked separately; I'm not an expert on SO, but I think continually moving the goalposts of an existing question is poor etiquette.

Comment: you are right, you answered my question, hence the accept. I solved the problem related to the syntax. now i have a temporary table space allocation problem. But as you said, that's another question